# i am using an RNN to generate text but it is saying the call arguments are incorrect

Tags: python, tensorflow, twitter, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to generate text using an RNN from my custom dataset of tweets. i have trained the model on colab and i am trying to call the saved model on my windows pc but i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\PROGRAMMING\currentProjects\PROJECT-FRNN\CODE\genText.py", line 108, in <module>
    oneStep2()
  File "I:\PROGRAMMING\currentProjects\PROJECT-FRNN\CODE\genText.py", line 99, in oneStep2
    next_char, states = one_step_model.generate_one_step(next_char, states=states)
  File "I:\PROGRAMMING\currentProjects\PROJECT-FRNN\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "I:\PROGRAMMING\currentProjects\PROJECT-FRNN\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 1129, in autograph_handler
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "I:\PROGRAMMING\currentProjects\PROJECT-FRNN\CODE\genText.py", line 71, in generate_one_step  *
        predicted_logits, states = self.model(inputs=input_ids, states=states,
    File "I:\PROGRAMMING\currentProjects\PROJECT-FRNN\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler  **
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "my_model" (type MyModel).
    
    Could not find matching concrete function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
      Positional arguments (4 total):
        * Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(1, None), dtype=int64)
        * None
        * True
        * False
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
     Expected these arguments to match one of the following 4 option(s):
    
    Option 1:
      Positional arguments (4 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 100), dtype=tf.int64, name='inputs')
        * None
        * False
        * False
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Option 2:
      Positional arguments (4 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 100), dtype=tf.int64, name='inputs')
        * None
        * False
        * True
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Option 3:
      Positional arguments (4 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 100), dtype=tf.int64, name='input_1')
        * None
        * False
        * False
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Option 4:
      Positional arguments (4 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 100), dtype=tf.int64, name='input_1')
        * None
        * False
        * True
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Call arguments received:
      • args=('tf.Tensor(shape=(1, None), dtype=int64)',)
      • kwargs={'states': 'None', 'return_state': 'True', 'training': 'None'}
```

What i expected to happen was for it to print about 100 - 150 characters, that would be what the ai has generated. I have looked on stackoverflow, tensorflow's documentation and google for help and i could not find anything helpful.
if someone could help and / or point me in the right direction to fix this would be a big help! The code that generated this traceback is below:

```
def oneStep2():
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow import keras
    from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing

    import time

    print("TensorFlow Version: ", str(tf.__version__))

    path_to_file = "I:\\PROGRAMMING\\currentProjects\\PROJECT-FRNN\\TrainingData.txt"
    text = open(path_to_file, 'rb').read().decode(encoding='utf-8')
    vocab = sorted(set(text))

    ids_from_chars = preprocessing.StringLookup(
        vocabulary=list(vocab), mask_token=None)

    chars_from_ids = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.StringLookup(
        vocabulary=ids_from_chars.get_vocabulary(), invert=True, mask_token=None)

    # Define a simple sequential model
    def create_model():
        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
            keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
            keras.layers.Dense(10)
        ])

        model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                      loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                      metrics=[tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])

        return model

    filepath = "I:\\PROGRAMMING\\currentProjects\\PROJECT-FRNN\\PROJECT_FRNN_MODEL"

    # Create a basic model instance
    model = create_model()

    # Display the model's architecture
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(filepath)
    model.summary()

    class OneStep(tf.keras.Model):
        def __init__(self, model, chars_from_ids, ids_from_chars, temperature=1.0):
            super().__init__()
            self.temperature = temperature
            self.model = model
            self.chars_from_ids = chars_from_ids
            self.ids_from_chars = ids_from_chars

            # Create a mask to prevent "[UNK]" from being generated.
            skip_ids = self.ids_from_chars(['[UNK]'])[:, None]
            sparse_mask = tf.SparseTensor(
                # Put a -inf at each bad index.
                values=[-float('inf')] * len(skip_ids),
                indices=skip_ids,
                # Match the shape to the vocabulary
                dense_shape=[len(ids_from_chars.get_vocabulary())])
            self.prediction_mask = tf.sparse.to_dense(sparse_mask)

        @tf.function
        def generate_one_step(self, inputs, states=None):
            # Convert strings to token IDs.
            input_chars = tf.strings.unicode_split(inputs, 'UTF-8')
            input_ids = self.ids_from_chars(input_chars).to_tensor()

            # Run the model.
            # predicted_logits.shape is [batch, char, next_char_logits]
            predicted_logits, states = self.model(inputs=input_ids, states=states,
                                                  return_state=True)
            # Only use the last prediction.
            predicted_logits = predicted_logits[:, -1, :]
            predicted_logits = predicted_logits / self.temperature
            # Apply the prediction mask: prevent "[UNK]" from being generated.
            predicted_logits = predicted_logits + self.prediction_mask

            # Sample the output logits to generate token IDs.
            predicted_ids = tf.random.categorical(predicted_logits, num_samples=1)
            predicted_ids = tf.squeeze(predicted_ids, axis=-1)

            # Convert from token ids to characters
            predicted_chars = self.chars_from_ids(predicted_ids)

            # Return the characters and model state.
            return predicted_chars, states

    one_step_model = OneStep(model, chars_from_ids, ids_from_chars)

    start = time.time()
    states = None
    next_char = tf.constant(['ROMEO:'])
    result = [next_char]

    for n in range(100):
        next_char, states = one_step_model.generate_one_step(next_char, states=states)
        result.append(next_char)

    result = tf.strings.join(result)
    end = time.time()
    print(result[0].numpy().decode('utf-8'), '\n\n' + '_' * 80)
    print('\nRun time:', end - start)


oneStep2()
```